# Why is XORing a string in c giving me garbage values?

Tags: c, string, operators, post-increment

I want to make a simple program which does the following,

1. Take Input string from user, char ip[50].
2. XOR each character
       of the string with the character '0'.
3. Display the thus generated
       Cipher Text, char op[50].
4. And using this string(op), again
       decipher the string and give the output same as input string.
       char rv[50].
5. Display the deciphered text.

So, for doing this I wrote the code below,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){
    int i=0,len;
    char ip[50],op[50],rv[50],b='0';
    printf("Enter the original text: ");
    fgets(ip,50,stdin);
    len=strlen(ip);
    //ip is input text
    //op is output cypher text
    //rv is again the input text obtained by XORing '0'
    while(i<len-1){
        op[i]=(ip[i++]^b); //XORing the input character with '0' and storing it in output string ^__^
    }
    op[i]='\0';
    printf("\nThe Cypher Text is: ");
    i=0;
    puts(op);
    while(i<len-1){
        printf("%c",op[i++]); 
    }
    i=0;

    while(i<len-1){
        rv[i]=(op[i++]^b);//XORing the output text again in hope of getting the input text back -__-
    }
    rv[i]='\0';
    printf("\nThe Original text again is: ");
    puts(rv);
    i=0;
    printf("\n");
    while(i<len-1){
        printf("%c",rv[i++]);
    }
}
```

but the output is always

## Output

```
C:\Users\cypher>gcc cypher.c

C:\Users\cypher>a
Enter the original text: qwerty

The Cypher Text is: ▄AGUBD
▄AGUBD
The Original text again is: Ω∞qwer

Ω∞qwer
```

Note: using puts() is just to check for any errors.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: my array starts from 0 to the string length

Comment: `op[i]=(ip[i++]^b);` side effect on `i` unsequenced with use of `i`, undefined behavior.

Comment: `op[i]=(ip[i++]^b);` invokes undefined behavior - `i` is being read and modified without an intervening sequence point.  Use `op[i] = (ip[i]^b); i++;` instead.

Comment: putting  `<len -1` to `len` isn't changing the output

Comment: well changing `<len-1` to `len` and using `op[i] = (ip[i]^b); i++;` solved it! thanks!

Comment: the output of `len` variable for the input `a` is `2`... so i guess i'll be using `<len-1`. can anybody explain why?

Comment: len = 2 means you must iterate from 0 to 1. If you use `< len - 1` it'll be `< 1` so you won't loop to the last character because 1 is not less than 1

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc thanks for your answer but, for a single character `a` the `len` variable should be `1` not `2`, that's why i was using `<len-1` so that it iterates only the **0th** position.

Comment: if you use `i<len-1` then when len=1, you get i<0 so the loop will only be executed for values of i that are less than zero. thus the case of i=0 will not be executed, since zero is not less than zero.,

Comment: No, it's not looping at all! Right at the first check `i < len-1` is false because i = 0 and len = 1. Loop by hand and see. But why don't just use `for` and avoid the hassle?

Comment: @FredK before this escalates any further, I was using the `<len-1` because the **value** of `len` variable, when the input was a single character `a`, was `2` **rather than the correct value** which should be `1` since its a single character, this was happening because of the `'\n'` character that was **being added to the string** due to **pressing ENTER** on windows CMD. That is the sole purpose of using `<len-1` in my loop.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc it does loop, it loops because **i=0** and **len=2** and the code checks `while(0 (value of i)<1(value of len-1) )`

Answer (score 2):

Statements

```
op[i]=(ip[i++]^b);
```

and

```
rv[i]=(op[i++]^b);
```

invokes undefined behavior because side effect on `i` in `op[i++]` is unsequenced relative to the value computation of `i` in `rv[i]`.

Change them to

```
op[i]=(ip[i]^b);
i++;
```

and

```
rv[i]=(op[i]^b);
i++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Statements like this

```
    op[i]=(ip[i++]^b); //XORing the input character with '0' and storing it in output string ^__^
```

have undefined behavior because there is no sequence point between expressions `i` and `i++` in the left and right sides of the assignment.

Moreover it would be better to remove the appended new line character for the input string as for example

```
ip[strcspn( ip, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

Thus the condition of the loop in this case should look like

```
while ( i < len){
        ^^^^^^^
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   50

int main(void) 
{
    char ip[N];
    char op[N];
    char rv[N];
    char c = '0';
    size_t i, len;

    printf( "Enter the original text: " );
    fgets( ip, sizeof( ip ), stdin );

    ip[strcspn( ip, "\n" )] = '\0';

    len = strlen( ip );

    i = 0;
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) op[i] = ip[i];
    op[i] = '\0';

    i = 0;
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) rv[i] = op[i];
    rv[i] = '\0';

    puts( ip );
    puts( rv );

    return 0;
}
```

the program output might look like

```
Enter the original text: querty
querty
querty
```

Comment: You just need ~100 rep dude!

Comment: the output of `len` variable for the input`a `is `2`... so i guess i'll be using `<len-1`. can anybody explain why?

Comment: @Paul The function strlen returns the number of characters before the terminating zero '\0'.

Comment: is pressing **Enter** on my keyboard adding a new character to the string? because the output of `len` for the single character `a` should be `1`, right?

Comment: @Paul You are right but it is better to remove the new line character. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

This program implements a coder that is it's own decoder.  But demonstrating that isn't convincing if you use separate code for coding and decoding -- you should define the coder/decoder as a function that you call twice to demonstrate that it truely is it's own inverse.

Specific problems with your code: you use `fgets()` which leaves the trailing newline (`\n`) in place which messes up both your encoding and your formatting -- I suggest you remove the trailing newline (i.e. replace it with `'\0'`) to make everything simpler; others have mentioned issues with using `i` and `i++` in the same statement, you could have avoided this by using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Here's a potential rework using the ideas mentioned above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (50)

void encode_decode(char key, const char *input, char *output) {
    size_t i = 0, input_length = strlen(input);

    // XOR the input character with key and store it in output string ^__^
    for (i = 0; i < input_length; i++) {
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key; 
    }

    output[i] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char key = '0', input[BUFFER_SIZE], output[BUFFER_SIZE], reverse[BUFFER_SIZE];

    printf("Enter the original text: ");

    (void) fgets(input, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

    *strrchr(input, '\n') = '\0';

    encode_decode(key, input, output);

    printf("The Cypher Text is: %s\n", output); 

    // reverse is the input text obtained by again XORing with key
    encode_decode(key, output, reverse);

    printf("The Original text again is: %s\n", reverse);

    return 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> ./a.out
Enter the original text: elephant
The Cypher Text is: U\U@XQ^D
The Original text again is: elephant
>
```